# Not understanding 2D Matrix algorithm question in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, algorithm, matrix

I am not sure how to proceed with this algorithm question.

Given a 2D integer matrix M representing the gray scale of an image, you need to design a smoother to make the gray scale of each cell becomes the average gray scale(rounding down) of all the 8 surrounding cells and itself. If a cell has less than 8 surrounding cells, then use as many as you can.

Example 1:

```
Input:
[[1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1]]

Output:
[[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0]]
```

Explanation:

For the point (0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2): floor(3 / 4) = floor(0.75) = 0

For the point (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1): floor(5 / 6) = floor(0.83333333) = 0

For the point (1, 1): floor(8 / 9) = floor(0.88888889) = 0

Note:
The value in the given matrix is in the range of[0, 255].
The length and width of the given matrix are in the range of[1, 150].

Questions:

Having trouble with my implementation logic: 
I am trying to check all neighbors I feel as if I am in bounds with my logic, but I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

The code I have written thus far:

```
const imageSmoother = (M) => {
    for (let rows = 0; rows < M.length; rows++) {
        for (let cols = 0; cols < M[0].length; cols++) {
            let val = M[rows][cols]
            let neighborsCount = 0

            if (rows >= 0 && rows < M.length &&
                cols >= 0 && cols < M[0].length) {
                //check right
                if (M[rows][cols + 1] !== undefined) {
                    val += M[rows][cols + 1]
                    neighborsCount++
                }
                //check left
                if (M[rows][cols - 1] !== undefined) {
                    val += M[rows][cols - 1]
                    neighborsCount++
                }
                //check bottom
                if (M[rows + 1][cols] !== undefined) {
                    val += M[rows + 1][cols]
                    neighborsCount++
                }
                //check above
                if (M[rows - 1][cols] !== undefined) {
                    val += M[rows - 1][cols]
                    neighborsCount++
                }
                //check diagonal top left
                if (M[rows - 1][cols - 1] !== undefined) {
                    val += M[rows - 1][cols - 1]
                    neighborsCount++
                }
                //check diagonal bottom right
                if (M[rows + 1][cols + 1] !== undefined) {
                    val += M[rows + 1][cols + 1]
                    neighborsCount++
                }
                //check diagonal bottom left
                if (M[rows + 1][cols - 1] !== undefined) {
                    val += M[rows + 1][cols - 1]
                    neighborsCount++
                }
                //check diagonal top right
                if (M[rows - 1][cols + 1] !== undefined) {
                    val += M[rows - 1][cols + 1]
                    neighborsCount++
                }
                console.log(val, neighborsCount);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The test case is below:

```
console.log(imageSmoother([[1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1]])) // [[0, 0, 0],
            //   [0, 0, 0],
            //   [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's maybe walk through a couple steps together to set you in the right direction. We start off with the following matrix:

```
Input:
[[1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1]]
```

What we're trying to do is look at a given entry and its neighbors.

For example, let's start with the upper-left number: `1`, which I will put quotes around to highlight for clarity.

```
[['1', 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1]]
```

There are 3 neighbors that it's "touching" (adjacent)—one directly to the right, one directly below, and one diagonal to the right and below:

```
[['1', "1", 1],
["1", "0", 1],
[1, 1, 1]]
```

They're asking us to consider the highlighted numbers and average them together and then round down at the end.

So to take the average, we will 1) add up the neighbors + itself, 2) divide by the amount of numbers we added together (see [formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/mean.html) for mean), and then 3) we'll round down as the question asks (floor).

`(1+1+1+0) / 4 = 0.75`

Now let's round down:

`floor(0.75) = 0`.

So the upper left hand cell should be `0`.

You would then do this for every number. To clarify what I mean by "touching", the next step would be to calculate for this cell:

```
[[1, '1', 1],
[1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1]]
```

Which has the following 5 neighbors (6 including itself):

```
[["1", '1', "1"],
 ["1", "0", "1"],
 [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: I have a better understanding of the question now, but I am having trouble implementing the logic, I have posted the code in my modified question, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution, I can come up with.  Not sure if there is a better way, but it seems to work:

```
const imageSmoother = (M) => {
    let result = Array(M.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Array(M[0].length)
    }

    for (let rows = 0; rows < M.length; rows++) {
        for (let cols = 0; cols < M[0].length; cols++) {
            let val = M[rows][cols]
            let neighborsCount = 0

            //check right
            if (M[rows][cols + 1] !== undefined) {
                val += M[rows][cols + 1]
                neighborsCount++
            }
            //check left
            if (M[rows][cols - 1] !== undefined) {
                val += M[rows][cols - 1]
                neighborsCount++
            }
            //check bottom
            if (Array.isArray(M[rows + 1]) && M[rows + 1][cols] !== undefined) {
                val += M[rows + 1][cols]
                neighborsCount++
            }
            //check above
            if (M[rows - 1] && M[rows - 1][cols] !== undefined) {
                val += M[rows - 1][cols]
                neighborsCount++
            }
            //check diagonal top left
            if (M[rows - 1] && M[rows - 1][cols - 1] !== undefined) {
                val += M[rows - 1][cols - 1]
                neighborsCount++
            }
            //check diagonal bottom right
            if (M[rows + 1] && M[rows + 1][cols + 1] !== undefined) {
                val += M[rows + 1][cols + 1]
                neighborsCount++
            }
            //check diagonal bottom left
            if (M[rows + 1] && M[rows + 1][cols - 1] !== undefined) {
                val += M[rows + 1][cols - 1]
                neighborsCount++
            }
            //check diagonal top right
            if (M[rows - 1] && M[rows - 1][cols + 1] !== undefined) {
                val += M[rows - 1][cols + 1]
                neighborsCount++
            }
            result[rows][cols] = Math.floor(val / (neighborsCount + 1))
        }
    }
    return result
}
```